# Figures not obeying margins

Tags: graphics, floats, scaling

I have a few figures in my document not obeying the margin constraints:

```
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
```

Most do. But these one's don't... they are defined as the others like,

```
\begin{figure} [p]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{old_zig_1}
\caption{Example of a forward looking algorithm that identifies peaks \& troughs.}
\label{fig:old_zig_1}
\end{figure}
```

Not sure why. Any ideas? What are my options...? Simply change the scaling...?

Comment: Superb. thank you. One more thing. Can I still use "scale" also or is that now obsolete?

Comment: You can still use `scale`. `width` is just a make things fit (or resize) within a certain horizontal width. Same goes for `height`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images that are included can be scaled or resized to fit within your needs in a number of ways. Using `scale=<num>` is one way, to enlarge (if `<num>` > 1) or shrink (if `<num>` < 1) an image. However, in order to make it fit within a certain constraint *exactly*, use `width=<len>`. For example,

```
\begin{figure} [p]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{old_zig_1}
  \caption{Example of a forward looking algorithm that identifies peaks \& troughs.}
  \label{fig:old_zig_1}
\end{figure}
```

will fit the image horizontally within `\textwidth`. For more options offered by the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), see the [`graphicx` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) (section **4.4 Including Graphics Files**, p 9).